# Unable to ping or tracert google hostname from docker machine in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, proxy, dns, docker-for-windows

I'm behind a corporate proxy on a Windows 7 machine. I'm unable to ping www.google.com from my VirtualBox docker machine.

I've tried so many different things, none seem to work :

- Added dns flag to both these files `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` & `/etc/default/docker` (I created it) :

`DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 192.168.1.254"`

- Created a new file `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker/` with dns information :

  `{
      "dns": ["192.168.1.254", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"] 
  }`
- Added google dns `8.8.8.8` to my `resolve.conf` file
- Modified my `C:\%User%\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json` file with dns information :

`"EngineOptions": { 
          "ArbitraryFlags": [], 
          "Dns": [ "192.168.1.254", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ],
          ...
}`

- Added the dns flag to my docker run commands

None of this worked.

I still can't ping google.com. And when I try to resolve API hostnames in my apps, I get this message : `temporary failure in name resolution...`

Can someone please tell me what should I do ?

Comment: So what do you want to reach and which protocol do you want to use? Ping/tracert - it is ICMP protocol by default and corporate http/https proxy doesn't help you with that. DNS needs UDP for name resolution - again corp. proxy doesn't help you. Corporate http/https proxy will be useful only for http/https request. I recommend you to contact your corporate admin, they should be able to provide you proper network configuration.

Comment: 192.168.1.254 is not a proxy, it's a DNS. I don't really care about pinging google hostname, but it is a side-effect of what I'm experiencing with my container's java which is not able to resolve the hosts of the API my apps are using. I have the exact same version of docker on another machine under the exact same corporate network and I don't have any problem with it.

Comment: Please update your question, because you don't care about pinging google hostname, but title and description are about pinging. Add more detail, which DNS record do you need to resolve, which DNS manages that record, protocol,  ....